# boost/interprocess как расшарить класс в памяти между процессами?

Tags: c++, boost, inter-process

Из [boost doc Obtaining information about a constructed object](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features.managed_memory_segment_information)

Пытаюсь построить класс в памяти, и потом в другом процессе его прочитать. Почему-то выдаёт другой адрес и вылетает `Segmentation fault`

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

class MyClass {
        public:
                MyClass();
                ~MyClass();
                std::string name;
};
MyClass::MyClass() { this->name = "init"; }
MyClass::~MyClass() { }

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
        if ( argc == 1 ) { // Parent process
                std::cout << "parent: " << std::endl;
                struct shm_remove { // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
                        shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
                        ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
                } remover;
                managed_shared_memory shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 1000);
                MyClass *myclass = shm.construct<MyClass>("MyClass")(); // Construct a named object
                std::cout << "parent see: " << myclass << std::endl;
                std::cout << "parent see: " << myclass->name << std::endl;
                std::string s( argv[0] );
                s += " child ";
                std::system( s.c_str() );
        } else {
                std::cout << "child: " << std::endl;
                managed_shared_memory shm(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
                MyClass *myclass = shm.find<MyClass>("MyClass").first;
                std::cout << "child see: " << myclass << std::endl;
                std::cout << "child see: " << myclass->name << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

запускаю

```
parent: 
parent see: 0x7f54974fc118
parent see: init
child: 
child see: 0x7f8431583118
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Не пользовался boost::shared_memory, но уверен, что он позволяет юзать только POD классы.

Comment: да, всё нашёл... нужно ему не обычный стринг, а нативный-кошерный `#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>`

Comment: То, что разные процессы видят один и тот же сегмент shared memory по разным адресам, это как раз нормально. Поэтому использовать указатели, используемые другими процессами  даже внутри этой области (не говоря уж о ссылках в обычную кучу), нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам.

Достаточно обычный `#include <string>`, заменить на interprocess-овский.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
```

И саму переменную объявлять не `std::string`, a `boost::interprocess::string`.

И ребёнок видет то что видет родитель и может менять, и его изменения так же увидет родитель. Точно так же надо отдельный, собственный vector, map и т.д. брать не из `std::`, а из бустов. [Полный список всех портов](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers).

---

Пример кода:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
// #include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

class MyClass {
        public:
                MyClass();
                ~MyClass();
                // std::string name;
                string name;
};
MyClass::MyClass() { this->name = "init"; }
MyClass::~MyClass() { }

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
        if ( argc == 1 ) { // Parent process
                // std::cout << "parent: " << std::endl;
                struct shm_remove { // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
                        shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
                        ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
                } remover;
                managed_shared_memory shm(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 1000); // Create a managed shared memory
                MyClass *myclass = shm.construct<MyClass>("MyClass")(); // Construct a named object
                std::cout << "parent see: " << myclass->name << std::endl;
                std::string s( argv[0] ); s += " child ";
                std::system( s.c_str() );
                std::cout << "parent see: " << myclass->name << std::endl;
                myclass->name = "step 2";
                std::system( s.c_str() );
        } else {
                // std::cout << "child: " << std::endl;
                managed_shared_memory shm(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
                MyClass *myclass = shm.find<MyClass>("MyClass").first;
                std::cout << "child see: " << myclass->name << std::endl;
                myclass->name = "step 1";
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
parent see: init
child see: init
parent see: step 1
child see: step 2
```